# JQGrid Grouping Event

Tags: jqgrid

I would like to know if there is any event that I can use while grouping to add an additional subtotal row(on top of each total) for each grouping key.
By Default afterInsertRow does not fire if grouping is enabled.

Any way to achieve this?

More details updated:

Hi Oleg, currently I am grouping the jqgrid by category column(I am displaying list of products). So for each category I am able to see the total column(summary). This works perfectly fine when I am fetching only active products. But I have a scenario when I am showing Active and inactive products the I want to additionally add another subtotal summary row where I aggregate only the inactive rows. The total summary row for each group should aggregate active and inactive rows and that is working fine as well. I just need a way to display the subtotals summary row only for inactive rows. This subtotal row should sit just above the total row for each group. I hope this makes sense you to.

Comment: Sorry, but you have to reformulate your question and to describe what changes you need to do in the grouping header. You should additionally think not in "events" fired after "adding" rows in the grid. Instead of that jqGrid build the whole grid bod at one operation. One the other side jqGrid have **callbacks** which allows you to change the content (the text) of cells of the grid. There are callbacks which allows you to change the text of the grouping row *during building* of the row.

Comment: @oleg, I have added more details to the question. Hope this makes little more sense

Answer (score 1):

I hope that I correctly understand your requirements. Probably you can just group by **two** columns `groupField: ["category", "inactive"]`. You can additionally consider to display the summary in the header: `groupSummaryPos: ["header", "header"]`. As the result you will have not exactly what you asked, but the grid will have very close information.